# Super Downvote? One downvote, 3 points reduced

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation-history

Picture will make it more clear:

[image: screenshot]

[Link to the user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1208634/user1208634?tab=reputation&sort=time).

I guess it's due to the user having 1 reputation and can't get below that but still - couldn't figure what exactly triggered this line of information.

Also thought maybe it's the automatic -1 for questions closed as NARQ but it was closed back in March 14 while the super downvote took place at March 30<sup>th</sup>.

Any ideas?

**More details**: when viewed by post, it shows "2 events" for that post:

```
-3   08:31  2 events     guideline for web devlopment
-1   08:31  downvote     
-2   08:23  downvote
```

So this looks like a bug with the group by time, showing two events that didn't happen in the same time together.

Comment: Ah, that must be the automatic down vote for misspelling "development"... ;P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We roll up events of the same type on the same post with no others in-between in the chronological view, this is so if someone gets downvoted 20 times you don't see 20 spam rows in the profile, there's no need for that when sorted by time:

- for recent days (the last 3 days) a more verbose view is applied (when you typically actively care about what's happening in more detail)
- for old days (more than 3 days ago) we roll up (which is what you're seeing today for March 30)

A tooltip hover over the vote will indicate multiple events happened here.

The reason for the -3 is the 1 rep floor, that downvote only had an effect of -1...so that's what we show.

Comment: Thanks, there is some sense in this.. :)

Comment: Confusing, but makes sense. :/